# Вывод даты на месяц вперед

Tags: php, дата

Такая задача нужно выводить текущую дату до такой же даты следующего месяца,то есть на месяц впееред.Вот сделал кое что,но такое ощущение что замудрил,если есть вариант получше просьба подсказать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="tbody">
                <?php if(!empty($users)) : foreach($users as $user) : ?>
                    <div class="tr">
                        <div class="td">
                            <div class="wrapp-img">
                                <img src="/assets/images/photo1.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <h4>
                                <?php echo $user['first_name'].' '.$user['second_name']; ?>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Project Manager</p>
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                            for($i = 0; $i <= $days_month; $i++) :
                                $day = date('j', strtotime($i.'days'));
                                $dayOfWeek = date('N', strtotime($i.'days'));
                                $weekend = $dayOfWeek == 6 || $dayOfWeek == 7 ? 'holiday-0' : '';

                        ?>
                            <div class="td <?php echo $weekend; ?>">
                                <a href='#modal-1' class=' modal-trigger disabled' data-modal="modal-1">
                                    <?php echo $day; ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: strtotime($i.'days') можно один раз вычислить, а так вроде никакого криминала нет.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

Вот я пользуюсь... Только для прошедшего месяца. Но главное принцип...

```
/**
 * @param $recordDate
 *
 * Возвращает дату прошлого месяца
 *
 * @return bool|string
 */
public static function last_month( $recordDate )
{

    $date_info = date_parse_from_format( 'Y-m-d', $recordDate );
    $year      = $date_info[ 'year' ];
    $month     = $date_info[ 'month' ];
    $day       = $date_info[ 'day' ];
    $lastmonth = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month - 1, $day, $year );
    return date( 'Y-m-d', $lastmonth );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

если нужно дата + месяц, то `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'))`

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date().' +1 month'))  
видимо так хотели написать?